Click a button after a modal disappears
I want my test to click a button after a modal has disappeared.
So I wrote this cypress script:
cy.get("shiny-modal").should("not.exist")
cy.get("#my_button").click

but it's not working,  because the modal still exist.
I want the button to be clicked when the modal has finished (disappears).
How can I do this?
Is there a function for continuously listening for a event be triggered?

Think in terms of the state of the page. First the modal appears, then it does not.
The following prevents the test executing .should("not.exist) before the modal appears.
// action that makes modal appear, cy.visit() or link click or form submit

cy.get("shiny-modal").should("exist)
cy.get("shiny-modal").should("not.exist)

// proceed with the rest of the test

Also try visibility check, in the case you do not know if the modal is removed or is just hidden.
cy.get("shiny-modal").should("be.visible)
cy.get("shiny-modal").should("not.be.visible)


What do you mean by 'modal still exists'? Do you need to do any action for modal to be hidden? Like clicking 'x' to close it. If so, you need to do this action.
If the problem is with the fact that modal takes too long to disappear and because of that you can't click the button then you can increase the timeout, as documented here
If the modal is not visible for you (as in human looking at the app) but it still exists in DOM then this 'should' assertion you're using will fail and you might need to use a different type of assert try one of those from documentation
